# Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("</mat-header-cell>

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-table

I am getting below error:

```
ERROR in Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("                                </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let order" class="{{orderColumn.fieldClass}}" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="orderColumn.fieldType == 'date'">{{order[orderColumn.fieldName] | date: globalDateFormat}}</ma")
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("ateFormat}}</mat-cell><mat-cell *matCellDef="let order" class="{{orderColumn.fieldClass}}" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="orderColumn.fieldType == 'text'">{{order[orderColumn.fieldName]}}</mat-cell>
```

Below is the code:

```
<mat-table  #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort #sort1="matSort"
    matSortActive="id" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="row">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-column-checkbox">
            Row
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="mat-column-checkbox">
            1
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
            
    <ng-container *ngFor="let orderColumn of newOrderColumns;" matColumnDef="orderColumn.fieldName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="{{orderColumn.fieldClass}}">{{orderColumn.fieldLable}}
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order" class="{{orderColumn.fieldClass}}" *ngIf="orderColumn.fieldType == 'date'">{{order[orderColumn.fieldName] | date: globalDateFormat}}</mat-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order" class="{{orderColumn.fieldClass}}" *ngIf="orderColumn.fieldType == 'text'">{{order[orderColumn.fieldName]}}</mat-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order" class="{{orderColumn.fieldClass}}" *ngIf="orderColumn.fieldType == 'Checkbox'">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                [checked]="order[orderColumn.fieldName] == 'True'" [color]="'primary'">
            </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-cell>

    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: Try using `[hidden]` instead of `ngIf` on those cells.

Comment: You can't use mafCellDef and ngIf together, you might use ngIf on ng-container & place mat-cell inside that container.

Comment: I would agree with @Piyush, use `ng-container` and put your `*ngIf` there.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple template bindings on one element. *matCellDef and *ngIf are structural directives and can't be together in mat-cell.

You can build the same by wrapping the element with a span or any other element. For example, you can try this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="orderColumn.fieldType == 'date'">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order" class="{{orderColumn.fieldClass}}"> 
    {{order[orderColumn.fieldName] | date: globalDateFormat}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: using ng-container is good idea as it does not render as html but resolves the issue.